# How to list SVN branches when maintained in unconventional way?

Tags: svn

I recently started working on SVN and I've got experience on GIT.  In my current organization SCM standards were not adhered

`ALL THE BRANCHES` were created under directory 'Trunk'.  There are number of folders inside Repo_URL/Trunk for ex

```
Repo_URL/Trunk/FolderA
Repo_URL/Trunk/FolderB
Repo_URL/Trunk/FolderC
Repo_URL/Trunk/FolderD and so on
```

'git branch -a' would yield me the list of branches.  How to list the 'SVN branches' from this folder structure ?

Because, I don't know which directories were created `using 'SVN CP'` and which were created `using just 'mkdir / CP'`

Is there any way to list the names of 'SVN branches' when they are maintained in an unconventional way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of branches in Subversion. Everything is a copy.
When you copy a directory, the resultant directory is only a “branch” because you attach that meaning to it. You may think of the directory differently, or treat it differently, but to Subversion it's just an ordinary directory that happens to
carry some extra background or historical information.

There is difference between subversion and other version control like git in a way that in case of subversion branches exists as just another filesystem directory. In case of git extra labels are added to it for identification hence you are able to get a list of these labels using

```
git branch -a
```

We have flexibility in subversion to put the branches wherever we want like in your case they are made in the trunk.

Now why

```
svn copy
```

command is use so to reduce file size on the server as when doing `svn copy` hard links are created to the original directory and hence saving space.

So when branches are kept in the branches folder of svn it is done so we can use the `dir` command to get the list of all branches.

Comment: What I meant was there are folders in 'Trunk' which does not contain any source code for eg a folder has got just 'word docs' in it, some has got only 'ppt's' in it and they are not related to SVN repo.  They are just normal folders.  In this case how to identify 'SVN repo' folders

Comment: You can use `svn list https://repo-url/trunk/` to see all the directories that are pushed into the repository for the latest revision. If you see those folders with word files in the `svn list` then they are in the repository.

`svn list` is a way you can see the list of "versioned directories". Non versioned directories will not be shown in this list.

Comment: Downvoted just because most of the answer is a copy-paste from the official documentation.